# Show the warning message upon outbound delivery item deletion in VL03N?

Tags: abap

I am trying to find a way of implementing the new warning message window in the standard transaction when the user tries to delete Item on Item Overview window.

Right now there is a standard warning window with "Delete selected item(s)? Y/N" question and after that, my custom window should occur.

[image: the warning message should be the same as in this picture, and it should appear after this image]

Because it is the standard transaction, I am not sure about the way of implementing that task. Should I look at enhancement or some other ways?

After exploring the code through the debugger, I found the line in which warning window is showed, Am I allowed to put mine part of code after call function for the first warning window?

The path is  SAPMV50A -> MV50AF0F_FUNKTION_AUSFUEHREN -> call functioin FUNKTION_AUSFUEHREN (after line 65)

Answer (score 1):

Use can use method `CHECK_ITEM_DELETION` or `ITEM_DELETION` of BadI `LE_SHP_DELIVERY_PROC` for showing your warning, here the official doc:

> This method is called before a delivery item is deleted. You can use this method to perform checks to see whether an item can be deleted, and if necessary, to then prevent deletion of a delivery item.

```
DATA: lf_error TYPE abap_bool.

delete_item(
EXPORTING
  is_xlips      = is_xlips
  if_check_only = abap_true
CHANGING
  cf_error      = lf_error
  ct_log        = ct_log
  ).

IF lf_error EQ abap_true.
 cf_item_not_deletable = abap_true.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way to add your customized message is by adding custom enhancement-point, and then implementing it with the message.

1. add an enhancement point where you need to implement the message

   - `enhancement-point <enhancement> spots <spot>.`
2. add an enhancement to this spot:

```
  enhancement 1 <name>.
      message 'my_msg' type 'W'.
  endenhancement.
```